# Misunderstanding about array pushing - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm seeing a behavior in PHP that I'm not understanding. Here it is :

```
foreach($food as $fruit) {
    $fruit["banana"] = "yummy";
    dd($fruit); /* returns "banana" => "yummy" */
}

dd($fruit); /* returns "banana" => "yummy" */
dd($food[0]); /* doesn't return "banana" => "yummy" as I expect it to */
```

For simplicity I am leaving all the die dump uncommented, but of course I am only running them one by one.

Why is my push not affecting the full array?

***The array looks like this***

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["name"]=> string(7) "Something" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
        ["name"]=> string(5) "Somewhere" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: And what does `$food` contain to begin with?

Comment: explain the downvote? I don't understand. I'm not asking for someone to code something for me, I'm not asking a question that is easily googled, or found on this site, as far as I know? Not like it's a function that I can access in the documentation or anything, no?

Comment: @user1732521 Please, edit your question instead of writting code in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change array elements inside foreach you need to use reference, because the values inside foreach are just temporary values that will not affect the original one.

example:

```
foreach($food as &$fruit) {
    $fruit["banana"] = "yummy";
    dd($fruit); /* returns "banana" => "yummy" */
}
```

Comment: +1, just put `&` like `foreach($food as &$fruit) {`

Comment: thanks a lot! I always thought they were getting affected